# What conditions are necessary for HPL (human pancreatic lipase) to activate?

Tags: human-biology, enzymes

What conditions are necessary for human pancreatic lipase to activate? Is there an optimal temperature or pH? How quickly does it take effect?

Comment: Check this out: http://www.123helpme.com/view.asp?id=123079

Comment: There are several different lipases, you might want to specify which one you're interested in. It might help to add your motivation for asking this question, so that we might better understand what exactly you are looking for.

Comment: @Danielδ Oh my. That is almost exactly the experiment I did the other day, except I got no results. I'm wondering if my lipase was kind of smurfed.

Comment: @MadScientist I was using a 10% lipase solution; that was all the information about the kind of lipase that I was given.

Comment: Which lipase do you have in mind? From which organism(s)? There are over 90 lipase genes in the human genome.

Comment: Doesn't lingual lipase have an optimal pH  around 4 - 5? That's why it can still continue its catalytic activity even in the stomach...

Comment: I wasn't aware that most lipases needed any activation at all.  wikipedia says it is secreted from the pancreas in active form.  It might be pH dependent because its a digestive enzyme, but most lipases are....

Comment: If a lipase did not need activation, there is the risk that it would digest membrane constituents before compartmentalization and secretion. I'd expect most lipases to have a signal peptide, which needs to be cleaved prior to activation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The protein referred to in the question is encoded by gene *[PNLIP](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/gene/5406)*, pancreatic lipase. From this [annotation of the protein](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/protein/NP_000927.1), I see that there is a signal peptide from amino acids 1 to 16. Thus, this signal peptide must be cleaved before the protein can be active in its digestion of emulsified triacylglyerides.

A [paper](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/19113953/) describes the structural changes induced in human pancreatic lipase by lowering the pH. The secondary structure of the enzyme is stable within a pH range of 3.0 to 6.5. At this pH, a reversible opening of the lid controlling the access to the active site was observed. So, there is another aspect of activation - pH and the ability to open the enzyme lid so that the fat molecule enters the active site.